# Overlapping UIViewController with another UIViewController Using Swift Programmaticaly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have this problem and I can't seem to find the answer so I asked here. I need to overlap 2 UIViewControllers. It is in a navigation controller. Each Controllers is using xib files as view since I am not using storyboard. It needs to be overlapped since the first controller is on live feed and I cannot afford to use a screenshot for background to make the live feed stay on while the user is navigating on the second controller. Any Ideas?

Comment: May be you can try a popover for this? https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try content views [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) [tutorial](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

and the VC which you want to overlap, you will not keep it in you navigation stack, you will have to make overlapping VC, child of the VC on which you want to present it, after making child you will add child VC's view as a subview to parent's view. in that way both view controllers will appear to be overlapping

Comment: That would be useful too but I did mine different and a little bit dirty. I used another view and brought it on the corner that it is not visible then I just animate it in when needed and adjusted its alpha. In that way when the view animates in, the background can still be seen.